# How to select a mission in LOTR: Battle for Middle-Earth?

Tags: battle-for-middle-earth

I just beat the good campaign in LOTR: Battle for Middle-Earth (the first one). Is there a way to select a single mission (ex Helm's Deep) instead of going through the entire campaign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, unless you go through the campaign and save your progress. Just don't overwrite or delete it and you can play it as many times as you want.